# Can I encode videos using NVENC in Handbrake on Ubuntu 19.10?

Tags: nvidia, graphics, encoding, hevc

I've just purchased an Nvidia GTX1050 card as my i7 3770 struggles to play HEVC files in Kodi. I'm wondering if it's possible to encode x264 to x265 using NVENC in Handbrake on Ubuntu as it is in windows as I don't see an option. Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: Not seen here: https://www.winxdvd.com/seo-img/handbrake-troubleshoot-tips/handbrake-nvenc-option.jpg ?